# PreRender phase very slow

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I've just encountered an performance issue on one of my pages. **base.PreRender** takes more then 12 seconds:

```
aspx.page   Begin PreRender 0.00577958119283298 0.000009
aspx.page   End PreRender   12.3006780015036    12.294898
```

How can I diagnose that is exactly going on during that PreRender phase? At first I thought it's an issue with database fetching, but as far as I know when PreRender occurs, then all databinding was finished.

Can it be that ViewState is the issue?

EDIT:
I've added this diagnostic code to my page:

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.Write("OnPreRender", "Start");
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        Trace.Write("OnPreRender", "End");
    }
```

Actually `Trace.Write("End");` line is executed straight away. And this is trace output

```
aspx.page   Begin PreRender 0.233399419245709   0.000010
OnPreRender Start   0.233407218080441   0.000008
OnPreRender End 0.233415320448565   0.000008
aspx.page   End PreRender   1.45992676325022    1.226511
```

Comment: What is this page doing?

Comment: In a nutshell: Binding an IEnumerable<Theme> to GridView. Just displaying data.

Comment: If you think viewstate might be the issue have you tried disabling it and seeing if it works better?

Comment: Where have you measured it? Is your [`PreRender`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender.aspx) empty?

Comment: Setting EnableViewState on Page || GridView control didn't fix it

Comment: Output is from trace.axd page. And I don't have my own PreRender handler

Comment: How many rows are you displaying?

Comment: Ok : in one databinding expression '<%# %>' I was calling a method that was extremelly inefficient...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each web control with a `runat="server"` tag on the page will also have an `OnPreRender()` method that gets called independently of the page.aspx `OnPreRender()`.  If you have any custom controls on the page it may be worth putting the same diagnostic code within their `OnPreRender()` method to fault-find further.

(sorry for writing this as an answer - haven't got enough rep to comment yet!)

Comment: No need to apologize... It appears to have been the answer and shouldn't belong in comments anyway.